# AFNetworking JSONSerializer vs. HTTPSerializer

Tags: serialization, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking 2.0 and have a `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` subclass `HTTPClient` that handles all of the HTTP traffic in my app.

I have set the `requestSerializer` property of the `HTTPClient` is set to `[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]`, which should encode parameters in JSON and put them in  the request body.

Thats all working, but some requests require me to have the parameters directly encoded in their URL instead of the default JSON format.
I thought about setting the `requestSerializer` property on a custom `AFHTTPRequestOperation`, but this class has no such property.

**TL;DR: Is there a way to set the requestSerializer property per HTTP request?**

Comment: Same limitation here. I'll let you know if I find a solution. From what I've seen, the requestSerializer is assigned per manager.

Answer (score 1):

`AFHTTPRequestOperation` doesn't have a `requestSerializer` request.  I think this confusion happens because you're thinking of the order of object creation incorrectly.

Here's what happens if you use the manager:

1. The manager has a request serializer
2. The request serializer is used to create an NSMutableURLRequest
3. The manager creates an `AFHTTPRequestOperation` and assigns this request to it.

So, if you want to make a request using a different request serializer, it's simple:

```
/* 1. Make a NSMutableURLRequest using your own serializer */
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [myDifferentRequestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:@"http://www.aol.com" parameters:parameters error:nil];

/* 2. Create an AFHTTPRequestOperation and assign this request to it. */
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager sharedManager] HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:success failure:failure];

/* 3. Start the operation! */
[[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager sharedManager].operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```